# Elegant way to handle broken connections?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm working on an app based on `discogs_client` library, which is based on `requests`.

I'm trying to find ID in `discogs` database for my mp3 catalogs, and save it to `sqlite` db. Application recognize some intel based on files tags and then there are couple of function, which are triggered one by one, and querying `discogs` db in a different ways of using that info. Some functions are quick, some are complexed and long. Sometime connection errors happen, sometimes the artist isn't found.

I want to know how to handle these errors in elegant way and effectively. I mean, I want to repeat function it stops, or, if its possible, repeat step of loop inside the function. Now I'm repeating whole application step - one catalog, which is very annoying when connection is broken on a last function run, after few hours of work previous functions.

I know that there is a way to make `try` / `except` statements with `continue` as an `except` instruction in a `while True:` loop, but I imagine that there is a quick and effective way to make it work like that instead of putting every simple function in a `while True:` loop exception statement.

Here is a set of functions:

```
def find_a_master(cat_attrs, f_attrs_list):
    while True:
        m_by_token(cat_attrs, 10)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_album(cat_attrs, 50)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_variations(cat_attrs, 100)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_token_cut(cat_attrs, 10)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_album_fuzz(cat_attrs)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_album_fuzz_excl(cat_attrs)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        if config.manual_mode:
            m_by_manual(cat_attrs)
        if is_found(cat_attrs, 'd_master'):
            break
        m_by_artist(cat_attrs)
        break
    return cat_attrs
```

Comment: Your loop is executed only once (because of the `break`). Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @DYZ well it is indeed useless. I believe, when io code it, i was under impression of `try except` statement letting me repeat whole application, and put `while True` loop here instead of use just return.